# Execute file from tinker laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to execute file located in my project from tinker. I saw suggestions to use `more filename.php | php artisan tinker` but it doesn't seem to work for me, it throws error `ParseErrorException.php`. how can I do it? I'm using Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a file before running `tinker` using:

```
php artisan tinker filename.php
```